# Font-size related to the container

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, font-size

I need the `.list` font-size to be related to the main container. I set it to 62.5% and added a 1.5em `font-size` to `.list`, but this setup is increasing the text size from the nested `.list` items as well.

I'm trying to accomplish the same behavior we have for rem units, but being able to use containers different from `body`.

Is this possible?

```css
.container {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

.list {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>
      <div>
        <div>
          <strong>Free</strong> as a bird
        </div>
      </div>

      <ul class="list">
        <li>
          <div>
            <div>
              <strong>Free</strong> as a bird
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <ul class="list">
            <li>
              <div>
                <div>
                  <strong>Free</strong> as a bird
                </div>
              </div>
              
              <ul class="list">
                <li>
                  <div>
                    <div>
                      <strong>Free</strong> as a bird
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not set the .list font-size to 1em?

Comment: If you remove the `.list` class from the nested uls, the font sizes don't grow